# how to make my own map into openstreetmap tiles standard for iphone

Tags: iphone, openstreetmap

i have my own map , now how to cut my map into openstreetmap standrad (their folder strucure)??

so that i can load those tiles into server and can access from there???

kindly suggest

Answer (score 2):

what you´re looking for is probably to find on the openstreetmaps wiki [slippy map tilenames description](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames)

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap consists of 256 pixel by 256 pixel tiles in `png` format.

There's a set of tiles for each zoom level.  The zoom level is the first level of folders in the directory structure.

The next level of folders is the tile x coordinate, based on the [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).  The name of the image file is tile y coordinate, followed by `.png`.

As an example, at zoom level 6, tile x coordinate 10, the 24.png image is California, near San Francisco.  That tile is referred to as the 10, 24 tile at zoom level 6.

[image: 24.png]